# How to create two side by side columns which are not equal in height using flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see in this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yELMrv , the red column's height is the same as the blue one even though there's less content. I want my red column's height to be determined by the content inside of it.

```css
.column-layout{
    display: flex;
}
.one{
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 3;
}
.two{
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='column-layout'>
  <div class='one'>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
    <div class='two'>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You add to `.column-layout` `align-items: flex-start;`.

This will cause all items of flex container to be positioned at the beginning of the container. However if you want only a certain child to be positioned at the start of the container you add `align-self: flex-start`

```css
.column-layout{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.one{
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 3;
}
.two{
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='column-layout'>
  <div class='one'>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
    <div class='two'>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked just like I wanted it to, thanks.

Comment: @Bobimaru great! Can you mark it as solved?

Comment: I would suggest [CSS-Tricks' guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as further reading, it's excelent.